# How to place a 3D object above the other one using ARKit?

Tags: ios11, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, xcode9-beta

I am working on a AR based POC using the [sample](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/PlacingObjects.zip) given by Apple.

Is there a way to place a 3D object above another 3D object in SceneKit?

For example I have placed a table above which I have to place something else like a flower vase. How to achieve this?

Because as far as I know, ARKit is detecting only floor surface and if I try to place the flower vase over the already kept table, it is placing it under the table overlapping the existing 3D object. Is this doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're making `hitTest`, you could check if there's any nodes:

```
let results = sceneView.hitTest(checkLocation, options: [.boundingBoxOnly: true])
guard let node = results.first?.node else { return }
```

Then you can place your new node as child node for touched node.